# MySQL password in Centos

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, centos

I have installed mysql, I set a password and pass in a json file using chef.It gets installed in Centos server ,but when I access with `mysql -u root -ppassword` it shows

```
access denied  root@localhost
```

So where I need to check password in centos,for ubuntu it is in debian.conf file and also for me no need to update  a root user password.Is there any option to verify our root password in centos server for mysql.

Thanks,
Indra.

Comment: Have you tried `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -ppassword` ? Have you flushed the privileges since setting the pasword?

Comment: Hi ,   Also i need to give permission to all users for all hosts  using mysql, i have used GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '%'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*5A7C40A7AD1F5227D9CAE5' WITH GRANT OPTION     When i login mysql with a another user in that mysql.user ,it shows access denied for that host.ANy idea guys?

Comment: Try GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO '%'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*5A7C40A7AD1F5227D9CAE5' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: But I need %@% all users to all hosts but when executing this query it completes successfully and also flush privileges.   -indu